# How to create identifier_hash in typo3's sys_file?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to import some files in Typo3 system using external php Script. How do I create hash field value like `identifier_hash` `folder_hash` `sha1` for **sys_file** table?

If I leave these fields empty there is error:

```
Attempt to modify record '3094' (sys_file_reference:3094) without permission. Or non-existing page.
```

Comment: What is the value of the cruser_id? If it is '0', try to set it to '1'. This should do the trick, too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this is to call TYPO3 API, 
therefore you have to place somewhere in fileadmin/ and then call

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\getFileObjectByStorageAndIdentifier($storageUid,
$fileIdentifier);
```

The hashIdentifier function in TYPO3 source utilizes the standard php-sha1 function, just in case you do not want to utilize the TYPO3-API.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = array(
  'folder' => 'images',
  'identifier' => 'images/foobar.jpg'
);

$identifierHash = sha1($file['identifier']);
$folderHash = sha1($file['folder']);
$sha1 = sha1_file($file['identifier']);
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer.